# Objective-C BufferedWriter

Tags: objective-c, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to find a BufferedWriter class in Objective-C. However, the only one that I could seem to find is for Java. Does something like this exist for Objective-C? Should I just try to replicate it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class `NSOutputStream`, created on a C buffer  with the factory method:

```
+ (id)outputStreamToBuffer:(uint8_t *)buffer capacity:(NSUInteger)capacity
```

and then manage the buffer separately.

[Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html) on stream programming.

[NSOutputStream class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html)